# How to use Silverlight's SLLauncher on Mac OS?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I want to circumvent the built-in OOB install mechanism of Silverlight. I was succesful on the Windows platform by utilizing the sllauncher tool:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Silverlight\sllauncher.exe" /emulate:"C:\path\app.xap" /origin:"http://domain.org/content/app.xap?launchArguments"
```

The Mac OS version also has a tool with the same name:

```
/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Silverlight/OutOfBrowser/SLLauncher.app
```

Unfortunately I was not able to find any documentation about this tool. Is it capable of the same functionality as the Windows version? If it is, how should it be invoked?

Comment: Good question! One significant difference I've found on MacOS is: there is no automatic path choosen when installing from browser, ie, the 'app' is downloaded to your downloads folder. So maybe, the tool is less 'powerful' on MacOS?

Comment: This is not completely true, the xap is installed into the home directory and the .app package does not work if you delete it: ~/Library/Application support/Microsoft/Silverlight/OutOfBrowser/id.domain.org/application.xap

Comment: Mmm, ok, I will recheck. I'm using Firefox, maybe that makes a difference?

Comment: You get a .app package in your download folder, but Silverlight also installs the xap into the mentioned directory. If you delete that directory the app will not work.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the details. It makes sense, the .app is used like the shortcuts created on Windows (desktop/start menu).

Comment: Have you tried to look inside a .app to see if you could find the command line you're searching for?

Comment: Unfortunately not a script, but an executable file is located in the app package: SilverlightApp.app/MacOS/Silverlight

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?